# Bootstrap Place Image Above Hyper Link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place the image above the text content. I.E something like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L4FG.png

```css
.button-link {
  background: #DBBC26;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 190px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="button-link" href="#">Download</a>
```

Comment: you need to move the link inside a to achieve that

Comment: set image to `display: block` as well

Comment: What image? There is none in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
 .button-link img{
 height: 20px;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
}
 .button-link {
 background: #DBBC26;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #ffffff;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 190px;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 0;
 letter-spacing: .2px;}
```

```html
 <a class="button-link" href="#">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L4FG.png"/>Download</a>
```

Comment: I upvoted long ago it due to my reputation it is not displayed here as i am new to stack and development

Answer (score 0):

So you have a link and an image, and you want to stack the image on top of the text in link.

and you have defined your link `<a class="button-link" href="#">Download</a>` and an image `<img src="#" alt="my image" />` The next thing you need to do is merge them

```
<a class="button-link" href="#">
    <img src="#" alt="my image" />
    Download
</a>
```

would be better if you wrapped link content inside a div

here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/gzmzo4un/